# Does Hasura 'Event Triggers' support triggers for their internal tables?

Tags: postgresql, eventtrigger, hasura

Does Hasura support any event trigger for their internal tables in hdb_catalog? Like, triggering to dispatch a HTTP request to somewhere if an event reached the limit of retries it was supposed to?